# Stack block lifespan

Tags: objective-c, stack, objective-c-blocks

```
int (^b[3])();
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    b[i] = ^{ return i;};
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    printf("b %d\n", b[i]());
```

In the first loop a block structure is created, then the address of this structure is assigned to b[i] element and then the block structure is destroyed. Question is why b[i] in second loop contains valid/same pointers to the last state of the block? I would expect the second loop to crash because the elements are pointing to invalid stack area.

I know this is not the best piece of code and I'm not using it. But want to understand why after first loop, when the block structure supposed to be destroyed, I have valid stack object.

Comment: Related: [Unable to understand the block's lexical scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647918/unable-to-understand-the-blocks-lexical-scope/6648368#6648368)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code exhibits undefined behaviour, since you are using a block outside the scope in which it was created. You should write this instead:

```
b[i] = [^{ return i; } copy];
```

The variable won't cause a problem because it is actually copied into the block's scope with a const-qualifier added. You can give the block write-access to the variable by declaring the variable with a `__block` qualifier, which has the odd side-effect of moving the variable (i.e., changing its address) from the stack to the heap when a referencing block is copied.

Comment: I know that blocks are starting up in stack and limited to scope if I don't copy to heap. But why the pointer is still valid?

Comment: Other than the blocks themselves, there are no pointers involved. The variable is copied into the block's scope. Since you don't make a copy of the block, the copy of `i` remains on the stack, and it's pure luck that using it in the second loop, when it's out of scope, still works.